# How do I build a query that crosses multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server

Here are my tables:

**CUSTOMER**

```
Cust_ID (PK)
Name
```

**ORDERS**

```
Order_ID (PK)
Cust_ID (FK)
```

**ORDER_LINE**

```
Order_ID (pk)
Part_ID (FK)
```

**PART**

```
Part_ID (PK)
Part_Description
```

Now I want to list the customer details, the part number and the description of the parts that each customer ordered.

How do i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx) will be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  c.*,
        p.*
FROM    CUSTOMER c INNER JOIN
        ORDERS o    ON  c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID INNER JOIN
        ORDER_LINE ol   ON  o.Order_ID = ol.Order_Number INNER JOIN
        PART p ON   ol.Part_Number = p.Part_Number
```

Have a look at

[Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

> An SQL join clause combines records from two or more tables in a
>   database.

[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

> The JOIN keyword is used in an SQL statement to query data from two or
>   more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these
>   tables.

And for some graphic examples

[JOIN Basics](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use "JOIN" using the FK, but from what I see you don't have a foreign key between "ORDERS" and "ORDER_LINE". Are you sure you're not missing something from the table definition, ie: ORDER_LINE should maybe have the ORDER_ID as a FK ?
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a simple straightforward `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT 
  c.Cust_ID, 
  c.Name, 
  l.Part_Number, 
  l.Part_Description
FROM CUSTOMER c  
INNER JOIN ORDERS     o  ON c.Cust_ID      = o.Cust_ID
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ol ON o.OrdeR_ID     = ol.Order_Number
INNER JOIN PART       l  ON ol.Part_Number = l.Part_Number
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an SQL "join", such as:

```
SELECT c.Name, ol.Part_Number, p.Part_Description
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN Orders AS o ON c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID
JOIN Order_Line AS ol ON o.Order_ID = ol.Order_Number
JOIN Part AS p ON ol.Part_Number = p.Part_Number
```

Be aware that without a WHERE clause, this query will return all all parts in all orders for all customers, which will really hammer the network and perform poorly on anything but a tiny database:

> WHERE (c.Cust_ID = MyCustomerID)

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) join syntax
[SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196318%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)  join syntax